# Does Spring Security provide a basic registration solution?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm new to Spring Security, I used it only for the authorization. I know, that Spring Security provides authentication and authorization solutions. Of course, in some cases registration is nothing more than checking a validity of email, confirmed password and so on, putting user's data in the database. Is there any Spring Security's code that should be used for the registration? I didn't find any registration tutorials (but there are a lot of login tutorials). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By now there is no standardized registration process. You need to write a Service implementing UserDetailsService an pass it to your authentication-manager (here a DAO is used):

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
  <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDao" />
</authentication-manager>
```

Check the Spring Security Docs: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/

Comment: Thanks. But you gave me a link of the Spring's documentation, not the Security's one.

Comment: Sorry, it is set to Spring Security 3 now.

Comment: That's all right. Do I really need to implement something? Is saving user details from the registration jsp with a help of Hibernate  wrong? I'm using `jdbc-user-service` in the `authentication-provider`. Do I overlook something in your proposition?

Comment: I never tried this without a custom service, but if your database is following some standarts this shuold work too, look here: [securityDataSource](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-auth-providers)